# Would this US Supreme Court question be on-topic here and likely to receive an answer?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

In Law SE I've asked [Between 1984 and 1994 US Supreme Court filings almost doubled but arguments nearly halved. Why?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/47842/24570) eighteen days ago. It was well received (+5 with 33 views) but so far not even a nibble.

I'm just curious if this question would have been on-topic here as well, and if so, if it might be more likely to receive an answer.

Comment: This question has now been migrated here https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/49675/16047

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, I think this question would be on-topic here.

Comment: Okay if I don't receive an answer there in a week or so I may just delete there and then post here, thanks!

Comment: Please don't delete and re-ask. Flag it on Law SE requesting moderator migration, and include a link to this meta question as "proof of pre-acceptance".

Comment: @Nij Thanks for your suggestion; I'm just curious why that's a better way to go. I usually try to avoid making extra work for mods, there must be some advantage to doing that way that you know and I don't (yet).

Comment: @Nij Also, for some reason I didn't receive a notification of your comment, I just happened to stop by here. I think that an `@uhoh` must have been necessary in this case.

Comment: It maintains the post history including commentary and votes, allows an easy reversal if the move is determined to be incorrect, avoids having duplicates on different sites (even when one is closed or deleted). And it's not a massive task to do, especially for sites where the moderator workload is not very high.

Comment: @Nij okay that's excellent and I'm convinced and have flagged for moderator attention, thanks! Just fyi once again lacking an `@uhoh` I did not receive a notification of your response. See [How do comment `@replies` work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/303080) found in [metaFAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/303080).